# After_update hook with :if syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, hook

I am looking to have my `after_update` hook only fire if the `status_was` value for my object was one of two values:

```
after_update :set_activity_log, :if => :status_was == 'In' or :status_was == 'Out'
```

I can get this to work with `#status_changed?` But then it still fires on all other possible status changes and I'm forced to add the logic to check on the In or Out in the callback method anyways.

I feel like this should be achievable in the hook definition instead of in the `set_activity_log` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Per the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless) you can pass a Proc to an ActiveRecord callback:

```
after_update :set_activity_log,
  :if => proc {|obj| obj.status_was == 'In' || obj.status_was == 'Out' }
```

Comment: Thanks Jordan, is that the same as lambda {|obj| obj.status_was == 'In' || obj.status_was == 'Out'}. Still very new to Rails I read right over that portion of the doc not seeing its application here

Comment: Procs and lambdas in Ruby are very similar. [Here's a very popular text on the distinction.](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/)